# Do Stack Overflow answers require original content?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, attribution

[I just answered a question on Stack Overflow and it left me wondering if it was a "good" answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290142/multiple-form-in-a-single-page-using-flask-and-wtforms/18293534#18293534) I know that my answer works and I use it in my own code, but all I really did was quote the relevant parts of two links that I included in my answer.

The only portion of the answer which is my own wording is the introduction paragraph. Both of the examples come from the article.

Which got me thinking, do Stack Overflow questions require original content? If you are just quoting someone else's work is there a standard format to indicate this? Should quoted answers be worth any reputation?

Comment: From what I understand, you're fine when quoting the relevant parts instead of just linking where you're getting the code from. It's not like most code is OC anyway...

Comment: Be sure to cite otherwise you'll be downvoted for plagiarism.